# How to save the result of a modified video with gstreamer?

Tags: video, scale, gstreamer, webm

I currently have a `.webm` file which I want to modify (scale it to different size), so I've learned how to do that, I've used the following:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=my_video.webm ! decodebin name=dec \
! queue ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=200,height=140 ! autovideosink \
dec. ! queue ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink
```

And it works like a charm, but how can I save the result that is being display, instead of just showing it?

Also, if you have some documentation about how to use `gstreamer` commands, I'll appreciate it.

**Update**

I've found a possible solution, I found documentation [here](https://www.technomancy.org/gstreamer/webm-convert/), and the pipeline I've used is this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=my_video.webm ! decodebin name=input ! queue ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=200,height=140 ! vp8enc ! webmmux name=mux ! filesink location=my_modified_video.webm input. ! queue ! audioconvert ! vorbisenc ! mux.
```

But, I'm still opened to suggestions, I think I can improve this process, if you know how, please, let me know.